# Docker app can't connect to external db server

Tags: docker, ssh-tunnel, web-applications, legacy

I have a legacy dockerized grails app (grails 2.2.1), that is trying to connect to a remote postgres server (not part of docker) but I keep getting connection timeouts.

I've tried several forwarding approaches, but those require changing the datasource url to "jdbc:postgres://localhost:5432/db" which I can't do or can't figure out how to do it.

Is there a way to override the grails datasource url from outside docker?
or alternatively is there a way to get the calls to 'remote_pg:5432' to go through a tunnel without changing the app url?

Thanks